# Copying a value from range "H" after inserting rows based on the range "F" value

Tags: excel, vba

I found a code that I use to insert rows based on the cell value:

```
Sub Add_Rows()
  Dim r As Long
  
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  For r = Range("F" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
    If Cells(r, "F").Value > 0 Then Rows(r + 1).Resize(Cells(r, "F").Value).Insert
  Next r
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

But I also need to copy the value of the cell with the same index as "F" into the inserted rows:

[image]

How can I modify the code so that rows are inserted based on the value of the range F and a value from the range H is inserted into these rows in parallel?

That is, the script should have logic: if the value of "F" is 2, two rows are inserted - and the value from the index "H" is inserted into these two new rows

In the code that I sent, I manage to insert rows based on the value from the index "F", but I can't supplement the code so that the value from the index H is inserted for each new row

Please tell me how to modify the code?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added a line after the `.Insert` that assigns the value to the "H" column of those new rows. I used the same dynamic range ideas that `.Insert` used to find the correct range for those new rows.

```vb
Sub Add_Rows()
  Dim r As Long
  
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  For r = Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
    If Cells(r, "F").Value > 0 Then
        Rows(r + 1).Resize(Cells(r, "F").Value).Insert
        Cells(r + 1, "H").Resize(Cells(r, "F").Value).Value = Cells(r, "H").Value
    End If
  Next r
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It works. Please tell me, can I add not three lines (if the value "F" = 3), but two? Since I already have one line with the value (the original line). Therefore, is it possible to focus on the value of "F" and add rows, but with the condition that the number of iterations should be: "F".Value - 1?

Comment: Yeah, Just add -1 inside the `.Resize` like `Resize(Cells(r, "F").Value - 1)`. Make sure to do it for both lines.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```vb
Sub Add_Rows()

  Dim r As Long
  
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  
  For r = Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
    If Cells(r, 5).Value > 0 Then
        Rows(r + 1).Resize(Cells(r, 5).Value).Insert
        ' insert h value
        Cells(r + 1, 7).Value = Cells(r, 7).Value
    End If
  Next r
  
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  
End Sub
```

Comment: This would only assign a value into the first inserted row, leaving the others blank.

Comment: Your IF statement uses `Cells(r, 5)` but it should be `Cells(r, 6)` to correctly check column "F". Same issue with the `.Resize`. And the 7's should be 8's to target column "H"